# Adding image to the data and data is coming from api in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart

i am fetching data from API but i also want to show image with the data which is coming from api. Note the image which i want to display is not in the api i want to insert manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can add manually String Or file image object into the model of data which is coming from api.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more